# Applying a Sitecore workflow for a particular user

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, sitecore-workflow

Is it possible to apply a workflow in Sitecore only for a particular user?

I want to apply a workflow when the editor edits any item, but don't want to apply a workflow on that item in case an Admin edits it.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First Question:
Workflow is applied to an item. Workflow, however, does have security around it. This means that you can have different actions/flows at a user (or role) level.

Second Question:
Users who have the "User is Administrator" checkbox checked on the "edit user screen" will in fact bypass workflow.

Comment: Thanks Sean . For my second Qeustion. I have that checkbox ticked for admin user but still get workflow commands and steps for that user when I edit that item (where workflow is already applied.).and when I edit that item using admin i have to go through workflow steps though its same user who can approve it .

Comment: I got this working. Only think I was not doing is not checking its state. so if item is in final state you can direct change and publish it without going through WF for Admin.

Comment: is it possible to ON/OFF workflow temparory ? or you have to remove it everytime you dont want to make item run through it .

Comment: I'm unaware of anyway to temporarily disable workflow. You could potentially add buttons to the content editor to remove/add a workflow to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Regarding turning ON/OFF, you can have a base template with the desired workflow, and add / remove it in the base inheritance for your templates. This will at least add / remove workflow for item versions that are not in a workflow already (so when those finish going through workflow and you have removed it from inheritance base, I presume new versions will not be jumping into workflow as it would be not set on base template).